# How to merge two List<string> into one List<KeyValuePair> including blanks?

Tags: c#

I have two List objects that I want to merge into one `List<KeyValuePair>`.  I know about `Enumerable.Zip`, but if the 2nd list is empty, then the resulting List is empty.  If the 2nd List is empty, I want the resulting List to include the blanks.  For example, if List 1 has `{"apple", "orange", "cherry"}` and List 2 has `{"", "", ""}` or has no elements, then I want the resulting List to be:

> 1) "apple, ""
>   2) "orange", ""
>   3) "cherry", ""

The only way I can think to do it is to do a foreach loop over List 1 (my "keys" in the `KeyValuePair`) where I add each Key with a blank value, then do a foreach loop over List 2 and overwrite each value as I go.  Although these Lists are separate, they are meant to be associated to one another (hence why I'm joining them).

Comment: Your statement of the problem is unclear. You say "2nd List is empty" but your example says "List 2 has..." (which is not empty).

Comment: You're right, sorry about that.  If List 2 is truly empty, then I would still want blanks attached to the key.  I'll need to consider all of these great answers and then mark the one I go with as the answer, hopefully in the next couple days.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could roll your own Zip method. It might look something like this:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<TOut> ZipAll<TIn1, TIn2, TOut>(
                                      this IEnumerable<TIn1> sequence1, 
                                      IEnumerable<TIn2> sequence2,
                                      Func<TIn1, TIn2, TOut> combiner)
    {
        sequence1 = sequence1 ?? Enumerable.Empty<TIn1>();
        sequence2 = sequence2 ?? Enumerable.Empty<TIn2>();
        var seq1Enum = sequence1.GetEnumerator();
        var seq2Enum = sequence2.GetEnumerator();
        for(;;)
        {
            var hasMore1 = seq1Enum.MoveNext();
            var hasMore2 = seq2Enum.MoveNext();
            if(hasMore1 || hasMore2)
            {
                yield return combiner(
                               hasMore1 ? seq1Enum.Current : default(TIn1),
                               hasMore2 ? seq2Enum.Current : default(TIn2));
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you could use it like this:

```
var a=new []{"hello", "world"};
var b=new string[]{};
var result = a.ZipAll(b, 
                      (aa, bb) => 
                         new KeyValuePair<string,string>(
                              aa ?? string.Empty, 
                              bb ?? string.Empty));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's `ZipAll`, a version of `Enumerable.Zip` that will return the default value for either collection type if either collection is shorter than the other.

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<TReturn> ZipAll<T1, T2, TReturn>(
        this IEnumerable<T1> first,
        IEnumerable<T2> second,
        Func<T1, T2, TReturn> f,
        T1 seed1,
        T2 seed2)
    {
        var iter1 = first.GetEnumerator();
        var iter2 = second.GetEnumerator();

        while(iter1.MoveNext())
        {
            if(iter2.MoveNext())
                yield return f(iter1.Current, iter2.Current);
            else
                yield return f(iter1.Current, seed2);
        }

        while(iter2.MoveNext())
            yield return f(seed1, iter2.Current);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TReturn> ZipAll<T1, T2, TReturn>(
        this IEnumerable<T1> first,
        IEnumerable<T2> second,
        Func<T1, T2, TReturn> f)
    {
        return first.ZipAll(second, f, default(T1), default(T2));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//create KeyValuePairs + fill shorter list with empty strings
var zip = a.ZipAll(b, (x,y) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x,y), "", "");

//create tuples + fill with nulls
var zip = a.ZipAll(b, Tuple.Create);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/INhbdg

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about `list2` being shorter than `list1`, then you need to append empty strings to `list2` to get a zip across lists of even lengths:

```
list1
    .Zip(
        list2.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("", list1.Count-list2.Count)),
        (x, y) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x, y)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select out with the index and join on their index.  This will do a left join the two enumerables on the their index allowing passing in the default value if it's not found.  This would work for more than just strings.  I added the default value since in your example is strings. String's default value is null so now you could just pass in String.Empty.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TFirst, TSecond>> ZipJoin<TFirst, TSecond>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
                                                                                IEnumerable<TSecond> second)
    {
        return first.ZipJoin(second, default(TSecond));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TFirst, TSecond>> ZipJoin<TFirst, TSecond>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
                                                                                IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
                                                                                TSecond defaultValue)
    {
        return (from l1 in first.Select((item, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, TFirst>(index, item))
                join l2 in second.Select((item, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, TSecond>(index, item)) on l1.Key
                    equals l2.Key into l2Group
                from l3 in l2Group.DefaultIfEmpty(new KeyValuePair<int, TSecond>(0, defaultValue))
                select new KeyValuePair<TFirst, TSecond>(l1.Value, l3.Value));
    }
}
```