# Create new list of objects from two different lists

Tags: c#, list

I have two Lists of the same complex objects, but each list has different data for the objects.

I need to get a new set of lists of those same complex objects, but combining them for the count of the lesser objects. I am not sure how to do this. I have tried to figure a way to union them, do addrange, and have tried using dictionaries instead, but this is a bit more complex than anything I have done before. I have found similar answers, but none for my particular scenario.

Here is the best way I can sample out the code:

```
List<Object1> ListA;
List<Object1> ListB;

ListA.count() = 5
ListB.count() = 3

new List<Object1> Object1CombinedList;

1. List<Object1> Object1CombinedList (Object1 (from listA), Object1 (from ListB))
2. List<Object1> Object1CombinedList (Object1 (from listA), Object1 (from ListB))
3. List<Object1> Object1CombinedList (Object1 (from listA), Object1 (from ListB))
4. List<Object1> Object1CombinedList (Object1 (from listA), null))
5. List<Object1> Object1CombinedList (Object1 (from listA), null))
```

I was thinking of somehow looping through the two independent lists to combine them for each pair as it went along. (I had thought I might be able to do that with dictionaries, but couldn't make it work). The end result is, I need a new set of lists (again all of the same complex objects), equal to the count of the length of the longest of the two lists.

The new set needs to contain matched pairs from list A and List B until the smaller of the two sets is exhausted, BUT still contain a single complex object for the remainder of the longer list.

The five lists shown above, are an example of what I need to get out of the two original source lists. (with a sample of their data).

Hope that makes sense? Asking this in the best manner I can.

Comment: Must it be a `List<List<Object1>>` (where the inner list contains exactly 2 elements)? Can it be a `List<Tuple<Object1, Object1>>` instead?

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking. Do you want 5 new lists?

Comment: I need it to eventually be a set of list objects, but I dont care if it starts as a dictionary, or something else first.

Comment: Yes the result is I need 5 new lists (the max count of the longest list).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I believe what you want is a `ZipAll` method. Pseudo code:

```
var listA = {1, 2, 3, 4}
var listB = {a, b, c}

ZipAll(listA, listB) == {(1, a), (2, b), (3, c), (4, null)}
```

Luckily, you can use a library called [Sequences](https://github.com/dcastro/Sequences) for this (disclosure: I'm the author).

```
ISequence<Tuple<Object1, Object1>> zipped = listA.AsSequence().ZipAll(listB, null, null);
```

- [Documentation: `ZipAll`](http://diogocastro.com/Sequences/?topic=html/d9622627-fa94-84cf-9062-203bbabab395.htm)
- [Source](https://github.com/dcastro/Sequences/blob/master/src/Sequences/Sequence%601.cs#L602)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to research into this some more and see if it helps. I can not add an outside library, but thank you for the consideration. I asked the question, in the best manner I could... I tried to leave  you a + on the feedback, but since I was down voted on this question so much, it wont apply.

Comment: @numlaar If you can't/don't want to depend on a library for a single method, use [this implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18707896/857807) instead.

Comment: @numlaar That's ok. It's not too late to improve/rephrase your question though :)

Comment: OK thank you, I will look into that. You understand at least what I am trying to get at. Its very frustrating to come on here as an inexperienced developer, do your best to ask a question, then get blasted and downvoted for it. Kind of defeats the purpose. I dont know how to ask it any better than I already did.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I was writing this as @dcastro was commenting. I used a similar idea of a `ZipAll` method, but found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342011/how-to-merge-two-liststring-into-one-listkeyvaluepair-including-blanks)*

---

What you are after is to zip both lists together, forming a new list along the way. Unfortunately the built in `Zip` method stops when one of the lists finish, so an implementation which does not do so is what you need - commonly called `ZipAll` - can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342011/how-to-merge-two-liststring-into-one-listkeyvaluepair-including-blanks)

Then this becomes fairly straightforward:

```
var listA = new List<string>(){"a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"};
var listB = new List<string>(){"b1","b2","b3"};

var combined = listA.ZipAll(listB, (a,b) => new List<string>(){a,b}).ToList();
for(var i=0;i<combined.Count;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} | {2}",i,combined[i][0],combined[i][1]);
}
```

The output is

```
0: a1 | b1
1: a2 | b2
2: a3 | b3
3: a4 | 
4: a5 |
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/PULLI83949

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I am after. Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

What about this

```
            List<int> A = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
            List<int> B = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

            List<int> C = A.Count > B.Count ? A : B;​
```

Comment: That simply returns the larger list. That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: Read comments : Yes the result is I need 5 new lists (the max count of the longest list).

Comment: Exactly, he needs a set of 5 lists. Your code returns 1 list. Read mine and Jamiec's answers to understand what the OP was looking for (granted, the question was somewhat cryptic).